# How can I find the close window button for automation in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to send messages automatically on LinkedIn. But I'm stuck in the phase of closing the chat window. How can I fix it?
It's my first time using Selenium. Please help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://linkedin.com")

time.sleep(2)

username = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@name='session_key']")
password = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//input[@name='session_password']")

username.send_keys("hr@unitedmerchant.com")
password.send_keys("UMSUpos2022")

time.sleep(2)

submit = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@type='submit']").click()
time.sleep(2)

import random

n_pages = 3

for n in range(1, n_pages + 1):

    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?network=%5B%22F%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&page=" + str(n))
    time.sleep(2)

    all_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
    message_buttons = [btn for btn in all_buttons if btn.text == "Message"]

    for i in range(2, 3):
        #click on "Message" button
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", message_buttons[i])
        time.sleep(2)

        #activate main div
        main_div = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[starts-with(@class, 'msg-form__msg-content-container')]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", main_div)

        #type message
        paragraphs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')
        
        all_span = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'span')
        all_span = [s for s in all_span if s.get_attribute("aria-hidden") == "true"]

        idx = [*range(3,23,2)]
        greetings = ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"]
        all_names = []
        
        for j in idx:
            name = all_span[j].text.split(" ")[0]
            all_names.append(name)
             
        greetings_idx = random.randint(0, len(greetings)-1)
        message = greetings[greetings_idx] + " " + all_names[i] + ", Sorry, I didn't mean to bother you, I'm just tesing a Linkedin capabilities... My apologies!:) This is not Bluu, this message is automated."
        
        paragraphs[-5].send_keys(message)
        time.sleep(2)

        #send message
        submit = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@type='submit']").click()
        time.sleep(2)

        #close div
        close_button = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'msg-overlay-bubble-header__control')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_button)
        time.sleep(2)
```

<Here's my error message. This section below is my Error message come up.>
There is a problem with closing the chat window. I even cannot find close trigger using finders in selenium.
Please help me.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JavascriptException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 5>()
     46 #close div
     47 close_button = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'msg-overlay-bubble-header__control')
---> 48 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_button)
     49 time.sleep(2)

JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.128)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector `[type="cancel-icon"].artdeco-button__icon`. You can either use

```
for button in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[type="cancel-icon"].artdeco-button__icon'):
  button.click()  
# can run into errors if the button isn't visible or if another element is blocking it
```

or:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('[type=\"cancel-icon\"].artdeco-button__icon').forEach(e => e.click())")
```

Which will close all open menus/chat boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried XPath using id and it worked.

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@id="ember304"]').click()`